# Difference of the Closest Multiples of Two Real Numbers

Tags: functions, algorithms, computer-science, special-functions, factoring

I am trying to find an algorithm / function for a computer program that I am working on. It looks like the following:

$$F(f_1,f_2) = \Delta $$

where $\Delta$ is to be the smallest possible difference among a constrained set of integer multiples of $f_1$ and integer multiples of $f_2$. To put it another way,

$$\Delta = \left\lvert n_1f_1 - n_2f_2\right\rvert\,\,s.t.\,\,\forall a_1,a_2 \in \{z_1,z_1+1,...,z_2\}, \left\lvert n_1f_1-n_2f_2 \right\rvert \le \left\lvert a_1f_1-a_2f_2 \right\rvert \; where\; z_1,z_2 \in \mathbb Z_{\gt 0}$$

Since I only need this for a very specific application, if it helps, we can also assume a few things about $f_1,\,f_2,\,z_1,$ and $z_2$:

$f_1$ and $f_2$ are musical notes from a 12 note, equally tempered scale. This means that $f_1 = (\sqrt[12]{2})^{c_1}f_0$ and $f_2 = (\sqrt[12]{2})^{c_2}f_0$ for some integers $c_1$, $c_2$ and some fundamental frequency $f_0$. Typically $f_0$ is $440hz$. This cannot be assumed here, but we can assume that $f_0$ is *some* known constant.

We can also assume that $z_1=1$ and $z_2=6$

Obviously, this problem could be solved very easily with a brute force computer program, as illustrated in the pseudo code below:

```
function(f1,f2){
      var delta = f1 - f2
      var temp = 0
      for(i=1;i<7;i++) {
         for(k=1;k<7;k++){
            temp = abs(i*f1 - k*f2)
            if(temp < delta){
               delta = temp
            }
         }
      }

      return delta
   }
```

But, there has to be a more elegant solution, right? Can someone help me out here?

Comment: I assume you mean to be taking the absolute values of your differences?
  For what it's worth, the assumption that $1\leq n_1,n_2\leq 6$ _drastically_ changes what's going on here.  If you instead allowed $n_1$ and $n_2$ to be any positive integers, say, then there would be no smallest possible difference in absoltue value assuming $f_1$ and $f_2$ are not rational multiples of each other (the differences get arbitrarily close to $0$).

Comment: Yes, I did mean the absolute value of the difference. Thanks for catching that! I have updated it accordingly. I had suspected that there wouldn't be an answer if $n_1$ and $n_2$ could be any positive integer, but I'm not sure how I'd prove it. In any case, impossible or not, it's well beyond the scope of what I need for my program.

Answer (score 2):

First, I'm not entirely sure what's wrong with the "brute force" approach: it will solve your problem, and will do so in a trivial amount of time on even the simplest and slowest computer.

However, let's say you wanted to solve the problem for much larger $z_2$. You are essentially trying to solve the *Diophantine approximation problem* of finding a "best" rational approximation to $f_1/f_2$, and the general approach is to look at the convergents of the continued fraction of $f_1/f_2$.

So for example, let's say $f_1=f_0$ and $f_2 = 2^{4/12}f_0$ (i.e. a major third).

We have 
$$f_1/f_2 = \cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{3+\cfrac{1}{1+ \cfrac{1}{5+\cfrac{1}{1+\ddots}}}}}$$
and the convergents are
$$1, \frac{3}{4}, \frac{4}{5}, \frac{23}{29},\ldots$$
so if $z_2 = 6$, you want $n_1 = 5, n_2 =4$; if $z_2 = 30$, you can do better by setting $n_1 = 29$ and $n_2 = 23$.

Comment: It's as simple as me wanting to learn something new, and that a different approach may or may not come in handy. What you've provided looks like the answer, but I've never heard of a Diophantine approximation nor seen a continued fraction before (which is great, because that means I am learning something new!).After some research, [I see how you calculated the convergents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_continued_fraction), but how did you choose the partial numerators and denominators? How does $z_2=6$ correspond to the third convergent in that series and $z_2=30$ to the fourth?